# Chromebook: Map Search Key to ctrl, ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard-layout, google-chrome-os

I've got ubuntu running on chromebook using [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

How do I map the search key to the ctrl action.

Similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-swap-or-remap-control-and-caps-lock-keys-in-xubuntu), swapping the caps lock key and the ctrl key.

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Acer C720 Chromebook, here is what I did to map search key to control

You can use `xev` to check the keycode for your search key, and which key it is mapped to. For my chromebook, search key is mapped to `Super_L` by default.

First, create file `.Xmodmap` at your `$HOME` directory with content below

```
clear control
clear mod4
keycode 133 = Super_L
add control  = Control_L Control_R Super_L
add mod4 = Hyper_L Super_R
```

Next, need to make sure `xmodmap` load `~/.Xmodmap` file when you start you linux using `sudo startxfce4` in chromebook terminal. Create file `~/.xinitrc` with content below

```
if [-s ~/.Xmodmap]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
fi
```

Last step is to logout your xfce environment and restart it from chromebook terminal.

For reference, you can look at Section `Special keys/signals` from [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)
And another reference from crouton: [Here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Keyboard)